# How to get the block in front of a block face?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I have a `BlockFace` object and I need to get the block in front of it. How can I do this?

What I mean is that if for example, I have a planks block with a wool block next to it on the west side, and I have the `BlockFace` object of the west side of the planks block, I get the wool block from it.

Answer (score 2):

Found it:

```
block.getRelative(blockface);
```